# Why controls inside a UserControls are accessable from outside the usercontrol?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have UserControl that contains a textbox, when i place this usercontrol on a form and make a loop of all controls i can see the usercontrol as well as controls inside the usercontrol, which means the TextBox which is located inside the user control are still accessable from outside the user control library

My problem started when I  want to list all controls of a form (including child controls located in a TabControl or GroupBox) i found out that even controls inside my UserControls are treated as part of form control, here is my code

```
Sub GetAllControls(Obj As Object, ByRef Controls As List(Of Control))
    For Each con As Control In Obj.Controls
        Controls.Add(con)
        If con.HasChildren Then GetAllControls(con, Controls)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub frmPHASE_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim ls As New List(Of Control)
    Me.GetAllControls(Me, ls)
    Dim St As String = ""
    For Each c As Control In ls
        St = St & c.Name & ","
    Next
    If St <> "" Then St = St.Substring(0, St.Length - 1)
    MsgBox(St)
End Sub
```

Comment: Because the `Control` class has been designed that way.

Comment: its because UserContol inherits from `Windows.Forms.ContainerControl` so in that regard - the ability to iterate child controls - it not any different than a Panel.  You can use inheritance to hide the child controls and expose the properties you wish.

Comment: If the controls used insude UserControls are exposed and accessable from application then this might be risky, i need to protect this by a way or another, how about commercial control in the market, are all internal controls are exposed too?... another question, how about the Modifiers property the controls? i set them to 'Private' but still i can access the controls from outside usercontrol! Help Please..